# How to declare an angular controller in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, angular-meteor

I am in angular's world since few months and I always have instantiated my controllers such that:

First I create angular.module:

```
angular.module("dummyApp", ['some-directive']).config(...).run(...);
```

After I can create a controller in this module:

```
angular.module("dummyApp").controller("dummyCtrl", function($scope) { 
   // some logic here
});
```

(The correponding html is in place).

Now, I am starting with meteor and angular together. And when I try declare a controller the error is (and I know what it means):

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'dummyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

how on earth I do this in meteor? I try this and a lot variants with the same result. Could be that I don't use `$meteor`? Syntax `ControllerAs`?

It frustrates me that something so easy take my time.

**Update**

Index.html

```
<body ng-app="EyEnsure">
  <div class="container">
<!-- Navbar goes here -->
<!-- Navbar goes here -->
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a ui-sref="Map">Map</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Page Layout here -->
<div class="section card-panel teal lighten-2">
  <!-- Aquí se insertan las vistas -->
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
<!-- end layout -->
```

Main.js:

```
angular.module("EyEnsure", ['angular-meteor', 'ui.router', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $stateProvider
            .state('Home', {
                url: "/",
                template: UiRouter.template('main.html')
            })
            .state("Map", {
                url: "/map",
                template: UiRouter.template('map.html'),
                //controller: 'mapCtrl', // I tried this..
                //controllerAs: 'map'
            })
    });
```

View where I would like show google map:

```
<template name="map.html">

<div ng-controller="mapCtrl">-->
<h1 class="center-align">Map to EyEnsure</h1>
{{tittle}}
<div class="party-details-maps">
  <div class="angular-google-map-container">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="party.location || map.center"
                        events="map.events" zoom="map.zoom">
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

MapController.js:

```
angular.module("EyEnsure")
    .controller('mapCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.tittle = "Hello!";
        $scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 45,
                longitude: -73
            },
            zoom: 8,
            events: {}
        };
    });
```

Just in case, my packages installed in `.meteor/packages`:

```
meteor-platform
urigo:angular
angularui:angular-ui-router
netanelgilad:ng-cordova
angular:angular-material
materialize:materialize
urigo:angular-ui-router
angularui:angular-google-maps
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not reproduce your problem (see [angular-meteor-demo](https://github.com/MatthiasEckhart/angular-meteor-demo)). Could you please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or share a repository which reproduces the issue?

Comment: I have updated my question, thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue wasn't how declarate angular controller but how meteor loads files.

My js manager to create angular app was in wrong directory. So I put in `clint/lib`.

The reason is [here.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)